# How to connect instances in CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, template, amazon-cloudformation

We would like to create a template for a fairly standard stack in AWS. We need three layers.

1. Layer: Elastic Load Balancer
2. Layer: several web servers which are created / destroyed according to alarms triggered by the demand on the site
3. Layer: a database server

Instances on Layer 2 should know the host name of the database instance. Ideally I would like to get hold of the private IP of the database instance and pass it through user-data to the web servers.

[Fn::GetAtt](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/) does not support the private ip (only the public)

I suppose an alternative would be to build the stack and afterwards to set manually the db private ip. It does though make our setup a bit less clean. We would ideally like everything to be described in the template. (even if this involves running a script through [**user-data**](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/index.html?AESDG-chapter-instancedata.html))

Any suggestions?

Comment: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-getatt.html is the correct link to the doc for GetAtt - and it _does_ in fact support the Private IP (nowadays at least)

Answer (score 6):

I do this now to add new nodes to my puppet master. For example, I grab the private IP of the puppet master instance in the UserData section of my new node:

```
"echo ", { "Fn::GetAtt" : [ "MasterOfPuppets", "PrivateIp" ] }, " ", 
         { "Fn::GetAtt" : [ "MasterOfPuppets", "PrivateDnsName" ] } ," puppet 
    >> /etc/hosts\n","\n",
```

See page 119 of the [CloudFormation User guide](http://awsdocs.s3.amazonaws.com/CFN/latest/cfn-ug.pdf).

Alternatively you could use the instance MetaData:

```
curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/local-ipv4/
```